# c# application, Handles in task manager increase and system hanged

Tags: c#

In our application we used Threads and Delegate to get the best performance.  In order to gate our operations we use the `System.Timers.Timer` class.
When the application start , after 1 hour the task manager shows that the number of handles increased and cpu usage increases as well.

What can we do to dispose objects of Thread and delegate?

below code can help you to check this task.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer MainTimer;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        MainTimer.Elapsed+=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(MainTimer_Elapsed);

    }
    Thread MainThread;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainTimer.Interval = 10;
        MainTimer.Start();
    }

    void MainTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoStart));
        MainThread.Start();
    }
    void DoStart()
    {
        PrintInfo();
    }
    delegate void PrintInfo_Delegate();
    void PrintInfo()
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new PrintInfo_Delegate(PrintInfo));
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += "Test\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "gate our operations" what does gate refer to?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov +1 for laughing Alot.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if I'm misparsing something, but it looks like once the button is clicked, you're then starting a new thread  (in MainTimer_Elapsed) every 10 milliseconds?  Without knowing more about the context / versions, it's hard to give  specific advice on an alternative (async/await, TPL, etc), but off-hand it seems like anything creating new threads (especially non-background threads) like that is doing so unnessarily?

For processing non-UI work, perhaps use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem instead of creating your own? For UI work, maybe use BackgroundWorker? If you're exhausting the thread pool, you could also consider setting things like max thread count, but using TPL and avoiding the use/creation/management of threads would be better/simpler IMHO if you're able to target .Net 4.x